# How do I have cookbook (A) compile and run before moving on too cookbook (B)?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I have a cookbook (A) that downloads some file from one of our servers and another cookbook (B) uses this file.

My problem is that when I run chef client the file is not there until the run list completes. In my metadata file for cookbook(B) it depends on cookbook(A) and the first line of code in the recipe is include cookbook(A). I also have cookbook(A) before cookbook(B) within the run list. When I run chef client the first time it does not do what I want it to, it says cannot find the file. If I run it a second time it works exactly as it should.

- How do I have cookbook (A) compile and run before moving on too cookbook (B)?

Comment: if you put that particular resource block in ruby_block it will be skipped at the time of compilation

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing after I read about them in coderangers blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really how Chef works. You can find a full description in https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ but briefly all recipes get compiled and then all resources get converged, regardless of cookbook/recipe divisions.

Comment: Individual resources in a recipe, such as a remote_file resource, can be executed during the compile phase with the .run_action method. In fact, any 'pure' ruby is executed at compile (like a puts vs a log resource). So if you want to ensure a file is downloaded you can do something like
`
remote_file 'foo' do
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)
`
or
`
my_file = remote_file 'foo' do
  action :nothing
end
my_file.run_action(:create)
`